How to Swap reverse order of the Raydium poolkeys?
I listen new pools on Raydium. As you might know most of the pools come with the token becoming base and sol becoming quote. In my script I also retrieve poolkeys in the same order. I want to swap sol for these new tokens but the order on my swap implementation is that sol for tokenA and the token for tokenB. Shortly, opposite order. if I switch the order when I try to get the poolkeys with fetching account with the poolID it returns null.
How can I achieve the swap successfully?
Thanks in advance.
